# Two methods of suppressing the save changes dialog in Excel are not working

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Before setting Application.DisplayAlerts = False]
[image: It gets set to false]
[image: Yet it still gives me the save as!]

For those who don't like images:

```
  Close logFile
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
  If WasOpened2 Then Workbooks(FilenameNoPath(FoundFiles(i))).Close False 
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Application.DisplayAlerts = False should suppress any and all alerts from excel.  Furthermore, I'm led to believe that passing False to .Close should automatically not save changes on the workbook.  Yet I still get a prompt.  Any ideas?

Comment: Also, feel free to lol at the dumb comments in there, they aren't mine.

Comment: Is FilenameNoPath an array or Function? I would assume a Function.

Comment: @PaulR It's a function, it does not close the file.  It only returns the filename without a path.

Comment: And there's nothing in that function that is changing .DisplayAlerts = True? That was the first thought I had.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the inkling that another Excel add-in that was running alongside could be causing the issue.
Coworker suggested to wrap with code to suppress events.  This worked:

```
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  If WasOpened2 Then Workbooks(FilenameNoPath(FoundFiles(i))).Close False 
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True
```